# How does sprintf('%d',A) - '0' work?

Tags: matlab

I was looking for a way to separate the digits of an array in Matlab i.e. 
if `A = 1024` then I would like it to be `A = [1, 0, 2, 4]`.

I searched on the net and found this code (also posted on the title):

```
sprintf('%d',A) - '0'
```

which converted `[1024]` -> `[1, 0, 2, 4]`.

It did solve my problem but I did not understand it, especially the `- '0'` part. 
can someone please explain how this works?

Also if I write `sprintf('%d',A) + '0'` (for `A = [1024]`) in MATLAB command window then it showed the following:

```
 97 96 98 100
```

this puzzled me even more can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes advantage of the automatic casting from a char array to a double array when the `-` operator is used. Remember that each character has an ascii value so if you type
`double('0')` in the command line and you'll see you get `48` as an answer. While `double('1024')` gives you

```
ans =

   49   48   50   52
```

`sprintf('%d', A)` just convert the integer to a string (i.e. a char array). The minus casts both sides to double so you end up with

`double('1024') - double('0')`

which is

`[49, 48, 50, 52] - [48]`

which ends up as `[1,0,2,4]`

From here it should be clear why adding `'0'` resulted in `[97, 96, 98, 100]`

Answer (score 2):

The command `sprintf('%d',A)` converts integer `A=1024` into a string representation of the number, `'1024'`.

In addition, a string in matlab is really a character array, so if `A = '1024'` then `A(1) = '1'`.

The rest of the explanation follows from the answer @Dan posted. When numeric operations (`+` `-` `*` `/` `mod` `^` ...) are applied to character arrays they are converted to the equivalent numeric representation according to the ASCII code, retaining the array format as type double.